# Private UI5 development

Tags: sapui5

I didn't know how to exactly name the title, but basically what I wonder is, how i would go about developing an UI5 application outside of my company, for the club I am in.

I do develop SAP UI5 applications at work, but there I have my odata pointing to the SAP backend and know everything I have to do there.

But with a "non work" application (for free + no issue with licensing when using it for my club (non profit)) I am wondering how exactly I would do that.

1. What IDE do i have to use (SAP WebIDE is out of the question I think)
2. I assume I need to use openUI5?
3. What Database can I use?
4. How does the connection between the database + frontend exactly work?
5. How does the transfer between frontend + backend work? also odata?

I think that's the basic questions for now I am curious about :)

Maybe anyone has done this too, from "work" development to a "private non work" development?

Comment: I have never acutally done it but here a few thought of mine:
1. You should be able tu use VSCode with `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ui5/cli`
2. Not quite sure about the licencing model for sapui5, but openui5 has almost everything. 3+4+5. I have seen some midleware to 'transform' e.g. MySQL responses into oData-structure, but I guess you could also make http-requests, save the response to a jsonmodel and bind to that.

Comment: I once made a *spending manager app* in UI5 for myself. There i worked with VSCode Studio. For Data Management i used [MySQL](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/11/connecting-sapui5-with-mysql/). I have to say it felt very unsatisfying having so much .php Files in the Frontend. But i bet there are better ways. If you have an Budget you could use Products like [OData REST API for MySQL](https://skyvia.com/connect/mysql-odata)